# How do I use POST request and filter() for field lookup and return a dataset through an html page?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

I want to get the values of attributes 'skill_required' and 'desired_level' from a user, filter the DB according to these values and send the matching rows of data through the html page 'emptracker.html'

Problem is, I can't figure out how to send this data through the html template emptracker.

The code for the view page is below:

```
def emptracker(request):
   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        skill_required = request.POST['skill_required'],
        desired_level = request.POST['desired_level']

        from app8.models import empskillmapping
        orgdata = empskillmapping.objects.filter(skill_required = skill_required).filter(desired_level = desired_level)

    return render(request, 'emptracker.html',{'data': orgdata})
```

I encounter an error here saying that orgdata is out of scope, I just can't figure out how to render this data.

*emphasized text*

```
class empskillmapping(models.Model):

    skill_required = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    desired_level = models.ForeignKey(level,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="", editable= True)
    department_id = models.ForeignKey(department,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="", editable= True)
```

This is the model I want to search.

Comment: You  can try `HttpResponse` instead of `render`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/views/

Comment: The reason this happens is because if someone makes a GET request, then `orgdata` is *not* defined.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is that if someone makes a GET request, then `orgdata` is *not* defined. You thus should do something in case the `if request.method == 'POST'` condition fails. For example return an empty queryset:

```
from app8.models import empskillmapping

def emptracker(request):   
    if request.method == 'POST':
        skill_required = request.POST['skill_required']
        desired_level = request.POST['desired_level'
        orgdata = empskillmapping.objects.filter(
            skill_required=skill_required,
            desired_level = desired_level
        )
    else:
        orgdata = empskillmapping.objects.none()
    return render(request, 'emptracker.html',{'data': orgdata})
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`empskillmapping`</s> to `EmpSkillMapping`.

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

Comment: This is actually sorted, I used the below code to get values for both attributes and filter the empskillmapping table accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually sorted, I used the below code to get values for both attributes and filter the empskillmapping table accordingly.

def emptracker(request):

```
value = request.POST.get('skill_required')
value1 = request.POST.get('desired_level')
selection = empskillmapping.objects.filter(skill_required =value).filter(desired_level=value1)
return render(request, 'emptracker.html',{'data': selection})
```

I now, have another ques :
I want to render the employee details of employees that possess a particular skill at a certain level.

To achieve that, I think that I have to render data from another table through 'selection' using a foreign key in empskillmapping, how shall I go about that?

'department_id' is the foreign key for employee and empskillmapping.

The models are below:

class department(models.Model):

```
department_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,null=False)
dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

class employee(models.Model):

```
employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True,null=False)
username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
department_id = models.ForeignKey(department,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="", editable= True)#foreign key to department
password = models.CharField(max_length= 30)
```

class empskillmapping(models.Model):

```
skill_required = models.CharField(max_length=20)
desired_level = models.ForeignKey(level,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="", editable= True)
department_id = models.ForeignKey(department,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default="", editable= True)
```